# Howto set outputdirectory with google eclipse plugin?

Tags: gwt, settings, google-eclipse-plugin

I'm using the Google Eclipse Plugin for GWT development.
To do the configuration stuff there's a folder .settings with two files
com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.prefs and com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.prefs.
These files are a kind of propertie-files.

Now I'm trying to set two different directories for source and output files.
But I can't find any documentation about these files.

What I got till now is this.

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
jarsExcludedFromWebInfLib=
lastWarOutDir=myoutputdirectory
warSrcDir=war
warSrcDirIsOutput=false
```

But using this, at compilationtime it opens a filechooser-Dialog on myoutputdirectory every time, waiting for confirmation.

So I ask, is there a solution to setup a different outputdirectory or does anybody know where I can find more Information about the usage of these setting-files.

Answer (score 4):

My version of that file has an absolute path to the `lastWarOutDir`.

Maybe it keeps prompting you because it can't find `myoutputdirectory` (or maybe you just changed it for privacy's sake here).

In any case, if you right-click on the `project > Run As > Run Configurations`, go to the `(x)=` Arguments tab and you will see the `-war` argument containing the value of `lastWarOutDir`.

If you want to be prompted so that you can change the directory, you could delete all of the arguments, forcing the Google plugin to reconfigure.

I hope that helps. If not, please let us know what you really want to do here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstand your problem. But why don't you just tell the GWT compiler where to output the files using the *-war* (*-workDir*, *-gen* and *-extra*) command line option? Same thing works for the GWT development mode...

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideCompilerOptions

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#What_options_can_be_passed_to_development_mode